# TypeError: (fn) is not iterable when just executing a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have a very simple code:

```
// doesn't matter, just be sure that we have an array
const tasks = Array.isArray(result) ? [...result] : [result];

// works
for (let i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
    this.executeNativeCommand(tasks[i].command, ...tasks[i].args);
}

// TypeError: this.executeNativeCommand is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
tasks.forEach(task => {
    this.executeNativeCommand(task.command, ...task.args);
});
```

Also tried `this['executeNativeCommand']` — it worked.  What sort of magic is it?

Comment: Huh. Just tried it, same result, but even the one where you wrote "works" causes the same error for me. Hold on, I'm trying to get to the bottom of it

Comment: Arrow functions dont have `this`: Either use a normal function or bind it

Comment: Yes but the outer code will have it.

Comment: I tried [here](https://repl.it/repls/OnerlookedHugeScandisk) but it works in both ways

Comment: Is that the exact code that is causing the issue? Sometimes people simplify it and it removes the error.

Comment: Could you write an example of the object of your 'result' variable?

Comment: @epascarello that's an exact code.

Comment: @Marlonchosky `{ command: 'setState', args: [ 1 ] }` or array of similar objects.

Comment: @Artyom same result that before, it works in both ways, review [here](https://repl.it/@MarlonEduardoEd/OnerlookedHugeScandisk#index.js)

Comment: @Marlonchosky see the accepted answer. Still confusing because `args` is a guaranteed  iterable, but that at least makes some sense.

Comment: @Artyom Yes, it's a weird behavior. What version of node are you using?

Comment: My only conclusion now would be that your `Array.prototype.forEach` function is overwritten somehow and doesn't pass what you expect. Maybe put a `console.log(task)` above the failing line and see what you get. Thing is, when I test your code with a bogus `result`, I get the (incorrect) error in both cases. If I put a correct `result`, like the one you just shared, it _works_ in both cases.

Comment: @Marlonchosky v13.9.0

Comment: @CherryDT I tried putting `console.log` — result was OK. It may be the `qode`, modified node.js for Qt front-end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message is wrong and confusing, it should be `tasks[i].args is not iterable` / `task.args is not iterable`.

You probably ran into [this V8 bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=10038).

It was [fixed](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git/+/1d0693e2eb40e521a008e26aa40c3b8f7222fc5a) three months ago (February 2020), but it seems it hasn't landed in stable node.js or Chrome yet.

Comment: Woah. You're the knight. Thanks a lot!